# derivative of $f\left(x_1\left(t\right),x_2\left(t\right)\right)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

What is the derivative of following function  $f\left(x_1\left(t\right),x_2\left(t\right)\right)$, where $x_1\left(t\right)$ and $x_2\left(t\right)$ are dependent on $t$?

Comment: Let $f=f(z,w)$ then $df(x_1,x_1)/dt=(f_z+f_w)x_1'(t)$

Comment: @Maesumi my apology for giving wrong function, actual function was $f\left(x_1\left(t\right),x_2\left(t\right)\right)$

Comment: **Hint** [Multivariable chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions) or [Total derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative).

Answer (score 1):

By the chain rule $\partial_t f = \partial_1 f\cdot \partial_t x_1 + \partial_2f\cdot\partial_t x_2.$